# Python: Print __name__ and import it in different scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes

**strong text**When I learn the `__name__` attribute in Python, I created two simplest scripts to test it out.

Script 1 (Name of Script: **test1.py**)

```
print __name__
```

When I run Script 1, it returns `__main__` as expected.

Script 2

```
import test1
```

When I run Script 2, it returns `test1` which is the filename of test1.py, and this is the expected result as well.

However, if I rename script1 from **test1.py** to **abc.py**, and update Script 2 to `import abc` and run Script 2 again, it shows nothing.

I have tried other random filenames for Script 1  such as **abcdefg.py**, **xyz.py**, **blabla.py** and update the code of script 2 accordingly, and each time I can get the correct output such as `abcdefg`, `xyz`, `blabla`, but whenever the filename of Script 1 is **abc.py**, running Script 2 will show nothing at all, why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

`abc` happens to be a name of a built-in module. When you do `import abc` you are importing *it*, not your `abc.py`.

```
import abc

print(abc)
# <module 'abc' from '\python-path\lib\abc.py'>
```

Its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), in case you are wondering.

As @user2357112 correctly noted in the comments, `abc` seems to be a little special in this aspect. Naming a script with a name of a built-in module (`random`, `json` etc) usually imports that script and shadows the built-in module. However `abc` shows a different behavior which is probably a result of how soon it is loaded during the interpreter execution.

Comment: With most modules, this would actually cause the local `abc.py` to shadow the stdlib `abc` module (causing nasty stdlib breakage), but `abc` is unusual. This may be related to how early it gets loaded at Python startup.

Comment: @user2357112 You are correct, I added that observation

Comment: Thank you @DeepSpace and @user2357112, so looks like I just ran into an interesting and unusual use case of Python by coincidentally using `abc` as the filename of the script and importing it in another script.

Comment: "abc" is indeed already in `sys.modules` at interpreter startup (tried with the python shell and in a script, with both python2.7 and ython 3.6).